# put images in the left of the div without using margin-right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put `3 images` in the `left side of the div`, without using `margin-right`:

[image]

I think of something with: `float: left` for the images, but it doesn't work.

this is my jsfiddle:[**myFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/vPc62/2/)

**html**:

```
<center>
<div id="container" style="width:700px;">

    <div id="header" style="background-color:rgb(249,204,157);">
        <font style="margin-bottom:0; text-align: center;font-size: 50px;">avb</font>
        <img src="image.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 76px; height: 60px; position: fixed; margin-right: 154px;">
        <img src="image.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 66px; height: 59px; position: fixed; margin-right: 85px;">
        <img src="image.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 77px; height: 62px; position: fixed; margin-right: 5px;">
    </div>

    </div>

</center>
```

**Style**:

```
<style>
#container { float: center; }

body {
  padding: 25px;
}

</style>
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: remove the position fixed from images!

Comment: Reather then putting `position:fixed` on your `img`, put it on its _container_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove your `position: fixed;` and mention your css styles like below... Don't need to write separate styles for every img..

```
img
{
    float: left;
    width: 76px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vPc62/6/)

Comment: thank you! can you put the `avb` in the center? I used: text-align:center but it's not in the center. margin: 0 doesn't work..

Comment: @AlonShmiel : its actually in the center just try to make the result in the fiddle bigger by dragging..!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `float: left` doesn't work because you have `position: fixed` on the images.
When I added this css, and removed the position: fixed it looks almost as in your picture.

```
img{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

And try to use classes instead of inline style. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <center>
<div id="container" style="width:700px;">

<div id="header" style="background-color:rgb(249,204,157);">
    <font style="margin-bottom:0; text-align: center;font-size: 50px;">avb</font>
    <img src="image.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 76px; height: 60px;  float:left;">
    <img src="image.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 66px; height: 59px;  float:left;">
    <img src="image.jpg" style="cursor: pointer; width: 77px; height: 62px;  float:left;">
</div>

</div>
```

it seems to work for me..

Comment: thank you! can you put the avb in the center? I used: text-align:center but it's not in the center. margin: 0 doesn't work.